# How to apply this. someFunction from promise in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I wont to apply this.func into promise.then scope, but this is 'undefined'. 
this is my code:

```
          const $self = this;
          this.myApi(params).then((res) => {        
             $self.func(res);
          });
```

gives me this error:  $self is not defined.

this code work fine:

```
         let func = this.myFunc;
         this.myApi(params).then((res) => {        
              func(res);
         });
```

and I dont understand the differance between them.

Comment: Odd. Both should work, as well as just referencing `this.myFunc` in the `then`. https://codesandbox.io/s/xym7rk18q

Comment: Something else is the issue here. We need to see more code.

Comment: thank's that's write, your exanple helps me to understand it!